# Chansen Stripe Version

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, stripe-payments, paypal-sandbox

I'am not a programmer and I just bought a php script but the payment gateway Stripe says that it uses a outdated api.

Here is the payment code:

```
else if ($request->gateway == "stripe") {
            try {
                $stripe = new StripeClient($this->settings->stripe_secret_key);
                $data = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
                    'success_url' => route('fund.verify', ['trans' => $ref]),
                    'cancel_url' => route('fund.verify', ['trans' => $ref]),
                    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
                    'line_items' => [
                        [
                            'name' => $ref,
                            'amount' => number_format($amount + $charge, 2, '.', '') * 100,
                            'currency' => $link->getCurrency->real->currency,
                            'quantity' => 1,
                        ],
                    ],
                    'mode' => 'payment',
                ]);
                $sav->update([
                    'charge_id' => $data->id,
                ]);
            } catch (\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
                return back()->with('alert', $e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException $e) {
                return back()->with('alert', $e->getMessage());
            }
```

And this is the error i get:
You cannot use `line_items.amount`, `line_items.currency`, `line_items.name`, `line_items.description`, or `line_items.images` in this API version. Please use `line_items.price` or `line_items.price_data`. Please see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migrating-prices for more information.

And i also want to use paypal in sandbox but then it gives me a Clint auth failed so i have to use production instead. Is there anyway to change that as well?

Here is the payment gateway code for that:

```
else if ($request->gateway == "paypal") {
            $authToken = base64_encode($this->settings->paypal_client_id . ':' . $this->settings->paypal_secret_key);
            $param = [
                'intent' => "CAPTURE",
                "purchase_units" => [
                    [
                        'amount' => [
                            "currency_code" => $link->getCurrency->real->currency,
                            "value" => number_format($amount + $charge, 2, '.', '')
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
                "application_context" => [
                    'return_url' => route('fund.verify', ['trans' => $ref]),
                    'cancel_url' => route('fund.failed', ['trans' => $ref])
                ]
            ];
            $curl = new Curl();
            $curl->setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' . $authToken);
            $curl->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            $curl->post("https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders", $param);
            $curl->close();
            $data = $curl->response;
        }
```

I would be very happy if someone could help me out with this.

Have read stripe's and paypal's api doc but doesnt understundom anything.

Comment: It is crystal clear by reading the documentation linked what the issue is, encapsulate the data with the `price_data` key and reformat the keys to be `currency`, `unit_amount`, `product_data` where `product_data` expects a further array of `name`, `description` and `images`. There is nothing unclear about this. Why not raise this with the developer since you paid for it and ask them to rectify and release a new version that supports the API changes?

Comment: Hi David - I recommend that you search yourself a programmer to do these changes or ask the support of the original author from where you bought it. Changing a payment gateway to a newer API version is no easy task for someone with no programming background. As stackoverflow is not a code writing service and payments are a sensitive topic I will flag that question to be closed.

Comment: The authour doesnt provide any support thats the thing.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of upgrading all of your code, it may be easier to find out what version of Stripe's API this code is meant to work with and then downgrade to that. In the stripe-php library, you can specify the version to use when creating your stripe client[1]. You also may be able to reach out to Stripe's support[2] to downgrade your account's API version.

```
  "api_key" => "sk_123456",
  "stripe_version" => "2022-11-15"
]);
```

If you want to change your code, you can look at Stripe's API reference[3] to see how to put these field's in to the new version of the `checkout->sessions->create` call[3].

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/versioning

[2] https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=php#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data